# UNTextInputNotificationAction change keyboard type

Tags: ios, notifications, keyboard, usernotifications

I implemented custom actions for my notifications via `UserNotifications` framework. I used `UNTextInputNotificationAction` in order to let the user input some text. Is there a way to define a different keyboardType like on a `UITextField` for `UNTextInputNotificationAction`? In particular I want to ideally present a numbers only Pad. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this?